# How do I change number of hidden layers when doing transfer learning with Tensorflow Object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Is it possible and advisable to change number of layers when doing transfer learning? How can I do it using tensorflow object detection api?

A typical model config file in the api looks like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config).

What should I change in the above file to increase/decrease the number of hidden layers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the number of layers is currently not possible using config files. The current settings have worked well for the datasets Object Detection was tried on. If you have very different types of images, you might want to try it, but you will have to dig into the code.